# How to test if a page is cached or not using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am about to play around with Hummingbirds Page Caching.
I need a confirmational tool to see if what I am doing is working or not, so...
How can I check it a page is cached or not using Javascript?

Cached pages are stored on the server - not the browser. For the browser to cache pages, a previous visit is needed. Wheras I am going to have page cached on my server, which means that first time visitors will also experience faster loading times.

Comment: Does Hummingbirds automatically invalidates the cache when there is a modification? If it is not the case you can try to make a small modification, if the modification doesn't show it means the page was cached. Still worth a try if you don't know if it invalidates, it's a quick test

Comment: Well yes, they have this option "Clear full cache when post/page is updated"...but of course it has to be tested. Regarding your method of making small changes and see if page updates or not...I am afraid that caching by the browser could interfere with my server caching. Do not know, maybe if I use incognito mode on browser or something...but this method does not seem as the most reliable.

Comment: Yes of course, you should disable browser's caching to test the server's one, as it should trigger first. Maybe reloading the page with CTRL+F5 is enough?

Comment: I guess I will do that. But it would be nice to have it fetch by javascript which would give me bigger modification options...

Comment: Yes these were just simple suggestions that can be tried quickly, maybe there are options in the Hummingbirds documentation that you can pass to test the cache, I don't know

Comment: Yes, but this would also be to test the Hummingbirds.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a page is cached or not using JavaScript, you can use the caches API provided by the browser. The caches API allows you to interact with the browser's cache storage, where it stores cached resources.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to check if a page is cached or not:

```js
if ('caches' in window) {
  // Check if the page is cached
  caches.match(window.location.href).then(function(response) {
    if (response) {
      // Page is cached
      console.log('Page is cached.');
    } else {
      // Page is not cached
      console.log('Page is not cached.');
    }
  });
} else {
  // Browser does not support the caches API
  console.log('Browser does not support the caches API.');
}
```

In the code above, we first check if the caches object is available in the window object. If it is, we use the match() method of the caches object to check if the current page URL (window.location.href) is cached. The match() method returns a promise that resolves to the cached response if it exists or undefined if it doesn't. Based on the presence of a response, we log whether the page is cached or not.

Note that the caches API is supported in most modern browsers, but not all. Therefore, it's a good practice to handle scenarios where the API is not available, as shown in the code snippet above.

#### References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

**EDIT: the snippet does not work on stackoverflow but should work in your browser**

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. But you have to distinguish between Page caching and Browser caching. As I understand it (could be wrong): cached pages are stored on my server, wheras browser caching is storing in the browser. Browser caching only works if the visitor have once previously visited the page, wheras page caching provides cached pages even to first time visitors, making the loading time much faster. And that is what I am looking for, to load pages faster even to new visitors. Seems like the answer you provided is regarding Browser caching and not Page caching.